# Add image in the header of the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I search since a good time with no result. Someone can tell me if it's possible to add an image in the header of my DataGrid in the column 3 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can looks like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Col1}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="H1" Binding="{Binding Col1Binding}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="H1" Binding="{Binding Col2Binding}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col3Binding}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="Image.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Your header if needed"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi, my last column is a DataGridCheckBoxColumn so I have try with DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header and it's ok.

But just a problem stay : I cannot do a HorizontalAlignment="Center" for the image... I have try many ways but no result :(